# urllib2 basic authentication

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

I'm trying to fetch an url which is protected by password

```
theurl = 'http://92.xx.xxx.x:80xx/connectioncounts'
username = ''
password = ''

password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
opener.open(theurl)
```

but always getting **urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**

I'm following https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/urllib2.html#id6

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved :) I must have used HTTPDigestAuthHandler instead of HTTPBasicAuthHandler.